# Fetch matching results from the integer array satisfying the condition which is given as text

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I've an array of integer data stored in a particular field in the user table. This array represents the groups in which the user belongs. A user can have any number of groups.

ie,

**Table: user**

```
user_id  |  user_name  |  user_groups
---------+-------------+-------------
1        |   harry     | {1,2,3}
2        |   John      | {4,5,6}
```

**Table: Groups**

```
group_id    |    group_name
------------+--------------
    1       |    Arts
    2       |    Science
    3       |    Security
    4       |    Sports
```

(Pardon, It should have been an 1-N relationship). I need to execute a query as follows,

```
SELECT * from user where user_groups = ANY(x);
```

where `x` will be text values Arts,Science,Security,Sports.
So when x= Arts, the result of `harry` is returned. The database that I'm using is `Postgresql8.4`

Comment: Are you **really** using Postgres 8.4? Then you should plan an upgrade to a supported and maintained version ***now***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@> contains`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-array.html) operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE user_groups @> (SELECT ARRAY[group_id]
                      FROM Groups
                      WHERE group_name = 'Arts')
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3dded/6/0)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

> Is there any way by which I could display user_groups like
>   {Arts,Science,Security}, instead of {1,2,3}

You could use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT user_id, user_name, (SELECT array_agg(g.group_name)
                            FROM Groups g
                            WHERE ARRAY[g.group_id] <@ u.user_groups) AS user_groups
FROM Users u
WHERE user_groups @> (SELECT ARRAY[group_id]
                      FROM Groups
                      WHERE group_name = 'Arts')
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3dded/26/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Is there any way by which I could display `user_groups` like `{Arts,Science,Security}`, instead of `{1,2,3}`?